# Python 2: ASCII issue when writing in Excel files

Tags: python, excel, python-2.7, utf-8, ascii

Problem sketch:

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

I'm trying to write a simple python program that can auto-complete the blank units with data appeared in the same column above.

Since there're Chinese characters in the file, I've thought of the issue of ASCII, so I tried to change it into UTF-8.

Codes shown below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
# -*- coding:utf-8 -*-
from xlrd import open_workbook
from xlwt import Workbook
from xlutils.copy import copy

rb = open_workbook('data.xls', 'utf-8')
wb = copy(rb)

sh = wb.get_sheet(0)
s = rb.sheet_by_index(0)
cols = s.ncols
rows = s.nrows

temp = 0
for cx in range(cols):
    for rx in range(rows):
        if s.cell_value(rowx = rx, colx = cx).encode('utf-8') != "":
            temp = s.cell_value(rowx = rx, colx = cx).encode('utf-8')
            print(temp) #to verify
        else:
            sh.write(rx, cx, temp)

wb.save('data.xls')
```

However, the issue still happened. Result in terminal:

```
ZishengdeMacBook-Pro:Downloads zisheng$ python form.py
(printed result ignored, and it looked good)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "form.py", line 41, in <module>
    wb.save('data.xls')
  File "/Users/zisheng/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/Workbook.py", line 710, in save
    doc.save(filename_or_stream, self.get_biff_data())
  File "/Users/zisheng/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/Workbook.py", line 674, in get_biff_data
    shared_str_table   = self.__sst_rec()
  File "/Users/zisheng/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/Workbook.py", line 636, in __sst_rec
    return self.__sst.get_biff_record()
  File "/Users/zisheng/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/BIFFRecords.py", line 77, in get_biff_record
    self._add_to_sst(s)
  File "/Users/zisheng/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/BIFFRecords.py", line 92, in _add_to_sst
    u_str = upack2(s, self.encoding)
  File "/Users/zisheng/anaconda/lib/python2.7/site-packages/xlwt/UnicodeUtils.py", line 50, in upack2
    us = unicode(s, encoding)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xe9 in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)
```

Anyone can help? Thanks in advance!

**I've figured it out!**

To solve this, we can add UTF-8 notation in the writing process:

```
sh.write(rx, cx, unicode(temp, 'utf-8'))
```

And it's done.

Comment: Well done on solving your problem. Instead of adding the solution to your question you should write your own answer and accept it so other users can see that your problem is solved. Welcome to Stack Overflow!

Comment: Thank you, I've posted my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved.

To solve this, we can add UTF-8 notation in the writing process:

```
sh.write(rx, cx, unicode(temp, 'utf-8'))
```